# Sum numbers if multiple criteria is met in other cells

Tags: excel, count, sum

I have an Excel spreadsheet with data laid out like so:

```
            Column A      Column B     Column C       Column D
Row 1        Sector        Rail
Row 2                      A            B              C
Row 3        Type 1        1            5              1
Row 4        Type 2        2            3              0
Row 5        Type 3        1            1              6
Row 6        Total         4            9              7
```

In row 1 you can see in column A I have sector, and in column B I have the type of sector, i.e. `Rail`. My spreadsheet has several occurrences of different data following this structure, like so:

```
             Column A      Column B     Column C       Column D
Row 1        Sector        Rail
Row 2                      A            B              C
Row 3        Type 1        1            5              1
Row 4        Type 2        2            3              0
Row 5        Type 3        1            1              6
Row 6        Total         4            9              7
Row 7      
Row 8        Sector        aerospace
Row 9                      A            B              C
Row 10       Type 1        0            9              9
Row 11       Type 2        3            3              1
Row 12       Type 3        4            5              6
Row 13       Total         0            1              8
Row 14
Row 15       Sector        Rail
Row 16                     A            B              C
Row 17       Type 1        8            9              9
Row 18       Type 2        3            3              1
Row 19       Type 3        4            5              6
Row 20       Total         9            1              8
```

Note that there are two sets of data with the sector `Rail` and one with `Aerospace` in the middle.

Now I need a formula that will add the numbers from the total in column B row 6 and add the total number from column b row 20. But only for `Rail`.

So Column B row 1 has a sector `Rail`, but so does Column B row 14.
So I need one formula which will find both occurrences of the word `Rail` and then give me the total numbers of row 6 + row 20, which would be 1 + 8 = Total of 9

Can anyone please show me if this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Please try deleting Row2 and:

```
=SUMIF(B1:B98,"Rail",B2:B99)
```

Comment: I can't delete row 2 I need the blank rows :(